# SqlCommand Error Procedure or function 'X' expects parameter '@Y'

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

As near as I can tell, this is not a duplicate question because I am supplying an alternative that actually DOES work.  VS 2012 targeting .NET 4.5

Common code:

```
public const string SP_PLANT = "hsp_BOM_EXP_SOURCE";
public const string SP_PARM_PLANT = "@Plant_CD";
public const string SP_PARM_PART_NUM = "@Mtrl_Number";
public const string SP_PARM_INCL_PURCH = "@Extend_BOM_Flag";

_SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(SP_PLANT, _Cnxn);
```

This works, but is a kludge.  It also proves I don't have some kind of spelling error or problem with the stored procedure I'm trying to execute or the connection I'm making.

```
  string sqlCmd = "";

    sqlCmd = string.Format(
      "EXEC [dbo].[{0}] {1} = N'{2}', {3} = N'{4}', {5} = {6}",
        SP_PLANT, SP_PARM_PLANT, "1234", SP_PARM_PART_NUM,
        PartNum, SP_PARM_INCL_PURCH, (InclPurchased ? 1 : 0));
    _SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    _SqlCmd.CommandText = sqlCmd;
```

This does NOT work, but should.

```
    _SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    _SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(SP_PARM_PLANT, SqlDbType.VarChar, 4);
    _SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(SP_PARM_PART_NUM, SqlDbType.VarChar, 18);
    _SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(SP_PARM_INCL_PURCH, SqlDbType.Bit);

    _SqlCmd.Parameters[SP_PARM_PART_NUM].Value = PartNum;
    _SqlCmd.Parameters[SP_PARM_PLANT].Value = "1234";
    _SqlCmd.Parameters[SP_PARM_INCL_PURCH].Value = (InclPurchased ? 1 : 0);
```

Error returned is: Procedure or function 'hsp_BOM_EXP_SOURCE' expects parameter '@Plant_CD', which was not supplied.

Comment: When it does not work, what is the SQL string you are executing?

Comment: the most common reason for this failure is when the parameter value is null; are you sure that isn't the case here? can we see a complete runnable thing from start to end that creates, populates the parameters, and executes it? Also: is `_SqlCmd` shared at all?

Comment: Are you reusing the same __SqlCmd_ variable for many commands? If you are doing that (bad) are you clearing the list of parameters between reuses?

Comment: just to be explicit, although I think you realise this: do not under any circumstances at all ever use the `string.Format` version :)

Comment: I notice your working example uses NVarChar but the nonworking example uses VarChar. How are the types defined in your stored procedure?

Comment: @MarcGravell I am positive none of the parameters are null.  Two values are given as literal values in my sample code and PartNum evaluates to a 9 character SAP number (but is a string).  I have checked the Parameter structures in debug mode - along with the SqlCommand - after they have been added and had values set.  Everything looks fine - that's why it's so confounding and why similar questions haven't been any help. _SqlCmd is a module var, but it's not really shared. Just wanted to set it up in one function, then iterate PartNum and Plant in another.

Comment: @Steve It's a module variable used in two functions. One creates and sets it up (the top four lines of the code block that doesn't work. And another that gets called as I iterate PartNum and Plant (which I give as "1234", but is really a passed in parameter).  I tested with literal values and also checked the values passed in. Everything looks fine and none of the 'wrong name', 'wrong command type', 'use DBNull, not null' similar questions have fixed my error.

Comment: @MarcGravell I would obviously prefer NOT to use the kludge of faking it with a text type command that actually executes the stored proc, but I'll go to production that way if I don't find a solution.  I care a lot more about the result than I ever have about the code elegance.

Comment: @DourHighArch You know, that is a very excellent point and something I had not noticed before.  I will bet that is the problem, but I can't check it until Monday.  I figured a second set of eyes would pick up on something stupid I was missing.  Pose that as an answer - untested - and I will comment or accept it as an answer.  THANKS, this was driving me nuts... and it's a short drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing like starting the week off with a little public humiliation... The problem was that I initialized the SqlAdapter incorrectly.

This did not work for a CommandType.StoredProcedure SqlCommand (for obvious reasons):

```
_SqlAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(_SqlCmd.CommandText, _Cnxn);
```

This worked fine:

```
_SqlAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(_SqlCmd);
```

I would have noticed that earlier except initializing with the command text actually automatically creates a non-null SqlCommand object for the SelectCommand property.  But that SqlCommand doesn't have ANY parameters on it, much less the ones I *carefully* created on my SqlCommand. Apologies to all who wasted their time trying to help me with this - particularly Marc Gravell who suggested I post a complete working example.

Debugging 101: The problem typically lies with the code you're NOT looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without supplying the @ at the start of your parameter name ?

I think it's not mandatory and result to a double @ in the final query text.

Like this :

```
public const string SP_PLANT = "hsp_BOM_EXP_SOURCE";
public const string SP_PARM_PLANT = "Plant_CD";
public const string SP_PARM_PART_NUM = "Mtrl_Number";
public const string SP_PARM_INCL_PURCH = "Extend_BOM_Flag";
```

Comment: `SqlClient` doesn't actually care whether you use the parameter `@` prefix in the name, as long as you do so consistently (via constants in this case)